Basement subfloor suggestions, going to finish my own basement
I'm looking to begin finishing my basement over the upcoming winter. For the subfloor, I have been told that using an uncoupling membrane, or the dimpled plastic that is used for exterior waterproofing ( (because I don't know what it's actually called.. I still call it uncoupling membrane) will work fine with some plywood on top of it, then it is either shot, or screwed in to the concrete floor. That is if I don't want to buy those 2' x 2' subfloor panels from Home Depot, or somewhere similar. Not sure which would be best for someone who is fairly handy, not a complete dummy, knows how to use Google/Youtube, and is willing to take the time to do it right.
Will that work? If so, what is the best way to apply it? Should I use some form of subfloor adhesive underneath the membrane, or will the mechanical fasteners I use to secure the plywood be enough?
I'll most likely be using some form of vinyl plank, or engineered flooring on top of it.

You haven't explained why you think you need to put something down in the first place. A concrete slab is a subfloor. Please revise to describe your home better, then tell us the what and why of your plan. Revise your title to ask a clear, specific question.

Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your personal relationships aren't any of our business. We just want the facts of your project.
